# trigger parameterized build on other projects does not pass parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a Jenkins pipeline, parameters defined in upstream job is not being passed to downstream job even "current build parameters" option is selected. When I try to echo the parameter value, it is null.

Example: I have checked "This is a parameterized build". There is a string parameter in upstream job called "version" with the default value as "abc". When I run  *echo $version* on the downstream job, in console output I do not see a value being printed.

Environment info:

- Jenkins Version: 2.89.3
- O/S: CentOs 7

Jenkins installed plugin info:

- Build with Parameters: 1.4
- Parameterized Trigger plugin:2.35.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that the way this parameter works in jenkins 1.x and 2.x versions is different. In the newer version of jenkins, all the down stream projects must be parameterized with the defined parameter and the empty value. However, in Jenkins 1.x was able to pass the parameter from upstream to downstream without defining the parameter in the upstream project. Using only "Current build parameter" was able to do the work but not anymore. Not sure If I am the only one finding it bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

In the downstream job you need to set a variable to accept the parameter being passed.

Example: If foo parameter was passed from upstream job. The downstream should have a parameter (string or one of your choice) same name as foo and default value as $foo.

Comment: I am not sure when you I need to set a variable to accept the parameter being passed. I have updated the post with my use case as an example, in case it helps.

Comment: I hope you know that the scope of parameter in execute shell is limited to that shell only, unless you have a global parameter defined in the initial section of Jenkins Job. That is the reason you get an empty value in your downstream job. Also i hope in your upstream job the value of version is not defined in execute shell of upstream job. The paramters/variables in execute shell will only be valid inside the shell

Comment: I am aware of scope of the parameter in shell scripting. Though I have again modified the example in my post above to make it clear that I am using a "string parameter" from "This is a parameterized build" option checked.